# How to store a user preference in a Metro App

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In Android, you can store user's config in "preferences" file. So where should the "preferences" being stored in a Metro app and how can this be accomplished?

Any example will help. Examples in Javascript would be the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Windows.Storage.ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) for this.

Example:

```
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;

var userSetting= applicationData.localSettings.values.userSetting;

//First run ? set default value
if (userSetting) == "undefined"){
    applicationData.localSettings.values.userSetting= 1; 
}
```

You can also take a look at the [Sample SDK app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2)